# Configuring Windows Bitcoin Core Wallet for use on Tor

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

I use Bitcoin Core v0.12.1 (64bit) for Windows as my desktop wallet for transactions on the regular web. I am just getting set up to use Tor. I would like to configure Bitcoin Core for use on Tor as well. When I opened Settings|Options|Network tabs I found a pre-checked marked box labeled "Allow incoming Connections" In addition to that I have checked marked the box labeled "Use Separate SOCKS5 proxy to reach peers via Tor hidden services" ProxyIP: 127.0.0.1  Port:9050.

Is this all that I really need to do? I've been reading up on bitcoin.conf and the command line options. It all seems horribly complex. I'm just an average schmo not some power user. I wouldn't know which options to pick or what values to assign. I would appreciate any thoughts and suggestions on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, following [this guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Tor) should be all you need to do.  It sounds like you've already done that.

Alternatively, I've found that it's cheap and easy to set up a [TOR wifi access point](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) that you can connect to, and then all network traffic is proxied over TOR.  That way, neither your local computer nor your Bitcoin Core installation need any special configuration.